# Does Word2Vec with high iterations work for very small toy datasets?

Tags: word2vec

I'm trying to run Word2Vec first on a very tiny toy dataset that I made up by hand -- just to convince myself I'm doing it correctly before I go for my main dataset. But despite doing 99000 iterations the results weren't great. (Tiger and Lion didn't have as high a similarity as I thought they would).

Toy dataset:

```
s= [['Tiger', 'Zebra'], ['Tiger', 'Lion', 'Cheetah'],
     ['Orangutan', 'Bonobo', 'Orangutan', 'Chimpanzee'],
     ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse'], ['Tiger', 'Rhino'],
     ['House', 'Car'], ['Antelope', 'Gazelle'],
     ['Zebra', 'Horse'], ['Tiger', 'Lion', 'Leopard'],
     ['Cat', 'Mouse'], ['Mouse', 'Hampster', 'Gerbil'],
     ['Rhino', 'Zebra'], ['Zebra', 'Antelope'],
     ['Tiger', 'Lion'], ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Giraffe'],
     ['Leopard', 'Lion'], ['Leopard', 'Tiger', 'Lion'],
     ['Tiger', 'Lion'], ['Tiger', 'Lion'],
     ['Car', 'Van'], ['Car', 'Lorry'],
     ['Car', 'Van'], ['Car', 'Lorry'],
     ['Car', 'Van'], ['Car', 'Lorry']
     ]
```

In theory should I expect a toy dataset like this to show amazing results if I did large amount of iterations?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(s, min_count=0, iter=iterations,size=100)
```

Ps. [See here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215637/word2vec-vector-quality-vs-number-of-training-iterations/284803#284803) for related discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, Word2Vec does not work well on tiny or contrived datasets. Sometimes, more iterations (or making the model much smaller in `size` dimensionality) can eke out some hints of meaningfulness – but nothing like the results from real multi-million-word training sets.

The true power of the algorithm relies on the balance-of-influences learned from large, diverse, naturally-varying text examples.

(As your synthetic dataset isn't even comprehensible language, I'm not sure what "amazing results" would be possible – what's the generalizable patterns that these short, repetitive lists-of-animals should be teaching a model?)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah my words are a substitute for my real dataset in which I'll be inputting song playlists. I wanted to get a feel for Word2Vec and my above example was trying to reassure myself that 'car' and 'tiger' would have low score given they never ever occur together, and 'tiger' and 'lion' would have a very high score given they appear together a lot, esp. in proportion to the tiny dataset. I chose these words rather than using song titles so that if anything is wrong it would jump out at me.

Comment: Are there alternative vectorization methods I ought to be looking at that work better for small datasets? My main dataset is a lot bigger than above but it still won't be the tens of millions I hear is needed for word2vec.

Comment: It's probably worth trying word2vec anyway – perhaps with appropriate iterations, vector size, & other meta-parameters it'll be indicative of relationships you want modeled. But to know if it (or any other technique) works, you'll need an objective evaluation of outputs - even if just a growing list of your own "A oughtta be closer to B than C" hoped-for results. (To the extent other categorizations of songs/artists are available, that may offer a rough evaluation method: does a technique under evaluation generally put an artists's songs closer, or those in external category X closer?)

Comment: If the dataset is too small for word2vec-trained dense vectors to be useful, perhaps it is also small enough to utilize the per-word sparse vectors that are just the traditional term-document co-occurrences. (That is, with N documents, they are N-dimensional vectors, with a 1 for each document that a particular term appears in.) Often similarities/classifiers/etc based on those feature-vectors are good, too.

Comment: Ok thanks all for the comments. Looks like I'll just have to go ahead and try it and see.

Answer (score 2):

With a small data like yours a general model quickly learns the parameters within just 10-20 iterations, doing more iterations would not result in much change in the prediction, if you may do a lot more iterations it may pick up the errors in the data and performance of the model may decrease. So from a small data it can only learn few things, if you train your model on more data your model may perform lot better.